# Using external monitor only via Displayport on Lenovo W510 results in "Out Of Range" error

Tags: multiple-monitors, thinkpad, external-display, displayport, nvidia-quadro

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad W510 and a ThinkPad Mini Dock Plus Series 3. I want to connect a iiyama 
ProLite XB2779QS to the docking station. To get the full resolution I only can use the displayport connection. If I use DP and I want to turn off the internal monitor from the notebook I get the error

> Out Of Range

on the iiyama monitor. Only the error message is displayed. There is no image at all (the internal monitor is turned off and through DP it doesn't work).

I tried
-to use another DP cable
-directly link the notebook with the external monitor

It is always the same result. If I want to use both screens at the same time everything works fine. Also if I use the DVI port on the docking station it works (though only in lower resolution due to single link connectivity on the dock).

How can I use the displayport connectivity on my dock to run the external screen only?

OS: Windows 7 64 Bit (all updates)
GPU: Nvidia Quadro FX 880M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deactivate the internal notebook monitor in the Nvidia system control. Now it seems to work.